# Encrypt string in Flutter and Decrypt in PHP

Tags: php, flutter, dart, encryption, cryptography

I am trying to send encrypted data from my Flutter application to my PHP server, but I am encountering issues with decryption on the PHP server. I am using the Encrypt package in Dart to encrypt the data with the AES encryption algorithm and then sending it to the PHP server, where I am using OpenSSL to decrypt the data.

Here is the Dart code that I am using to encrypt the data:

```
import 'package:encrypt/encrypt.dart' as encrypt;
void main() async {
   var plainText='test';
   final key = encrypt.Key.fromUtf8('AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA');
   final iv  = encrypt.IV.fromUtf8('AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA');

   final encrypter = encrypt.Encrypter(encrypt.AES(key));

   final encrypted = encrypter.encrypt(plainText, iv: iv);

   print(encrypted.base64);
}
```

This code outputs "VBnTmnNX14Sbxqu99PMtWw==".

On the PHP side, I am using the following code to decrypt the data:

```
// The encrypted string
$encrypted = "VBnTmnNX14Sbxqu99PMtWw==";

// The encryption key and initialization vector (IV)
$key = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA";
$iv = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA";

// Decrypt the string
$decrypted = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($encrypted), 'AES-192-CBC', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);

// Output the decrypted string
echo var_dump($decrypted);
```

And this outputs "bool(false)" which means the encryption has failed.

Why does it fail, any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key used is 32 bytes, so AES-256 must be applied on the PHP side. Also, the Dart side automatically uses CTR mode (equivalent to SIC mode, which is the default on the Dart side), requiring `AES-256-CTR` on the PHP side (instead of `AES-192-CBC`).

Be aware that the Dart code applies PKCS#7 padding (which is actually not required for a stream cipher mode like CTR). On the PHP side, padding is *implicitly* disabled for CTR. Therefore, the padding bytes are not removed. The correct fix is to disable padding for CTR on the Dart side (see [here](https://pub.dev/packages/encrypt#usage), section *No/zero padding*).

Also note that the key and IV used (as well as a static IV) are vulnerabilities (unless they were chosen that way for testing purposes only).

Comment: Yes this was the problem by changing the encryption to AES-256-CTR to code worked. 
Thanks !! :D

Comment: I have another question since you mentioned the vulnerabilities, since my clients already use the application with this encryption, am i able to change the encryption or will it get me in trouble with the existing files ? (When using encrypt.IV.fromLength(16) i have an iv with 16 0 bytes)

Comment: @Chris - When the encryption logic is changed, the old data must generally be migrated (decryption with the old logic, re-encryption with the new logic). Note that CTR in conjunction with a static IV (e.g. zero IV) is a serious vulnerability, s. [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/2991).

Comment: @Chris - One approach to avoid this problem is to generate a random IV for each encryption and pass it along with the ciphertext to the decrypting side, usually concatenated (the IV is not a secret), s. e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4951468/9014097).

Comment: But when the IV is not a secret why not using a static. The attacker can get the iv from the ciphertext so what is the difference between this or using a static?

Comment: @Chris - A static IV leads (when using a fixed key, which is usually the case) to a reuse of key-IV pairs making the encryption vulnerable. Look at the references, it is described there.